# Get data from sqllite and display it on html page in Django

Tags: python, django

I'am trying to display data from the database file which has the value Age : 50 but 
i alway get "Age object" displayed in the html. I'm very new too Django.
Here is the code

```
//base.HTML displays :
Age object

//base.html code :
<body>
{{ obj }}
</body>

//views.py : 
 def home(request):
    obj = Age.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("base.html",{'obj': obj})

//models.py
class Age(models.Model):
        age = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply `obj` is an array of objects, you have to print *the attribute of the object*.

If you want to show only one `age`(the first) you have to do:

```
//views.py : 
 def home(request):
    obj = Age.objects.all()[0]
    return render_to_response("base.html",{'obj': obj})

//base.html code :
<body>
{{ obj.age }}
</body>
```

Comment: or do as [Chris Lacasse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9167043/1089668) says: implement `Age.__unicode__()` to return age attribute so instead of doing `{{obj.age))` you can write only `{{obj}}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what field to show.

```
{{ obj.age }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either do obj.age in the template, or implement str or unicode method on your object that returns the age.